# Run time error: 1004 when changing chart formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on a sheet where I need to edit the formula of a Chart.

It all worked fine when I first wrote it but now I can't even have VBA read the formula, although it can still read the Name. I don't know what could have caused this.

```
Sub test()
Dim ser As Series

[irrelevant code]

            With Worksheets("sheetX")
                For Each ser In .ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart.SeriesCollection
                Debug.Print ser.Name
                'prints the name without a problem
                Debug.Print ser.Formula
                'Run time error: 1004 Application or object defined error

                [irrelevant code]
```

-the chart has a formula which I can edit in Excel but not in VBA

-when I cut the chart and paste it back in everything works all the sudden, I can't use `cut` in vba though because it returns the same error.

Comment: What is the formula?

Comment: @mooseman it is a standard chart formula along the lines of =series(range1,range2,1)
I can get you the exact one tomorrow if you like.

Comment: I can't replicate your error, so Vityata and I are just taking stabs at the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code and see whether it works? Simply make sure that you have one chart on the active sheet:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim ser As Series

    For Each ser In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection
        Debug.Print ser.Name
        Debug.Print ser.Formula
    Next ser

End Sub
```

As a guess, probably the name of `sheetX` is changed to something else or the name of the chart `Chart 2` is changed through the copy+paste.

Comment: That wouldn't explain why the Debug.Print ser.Name, still works.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll have to wait till tomorrow to try this out though.

As far as I can remember, the chart name stayed the same at all time

Comment: So I tried this and the first time it worked, but from then on it didnt again.

Comment: So i tried changing the chart type, cutting and pasting again, deleted all my charts and made new ones and I still cant get it to work

Answer (score 0):

I am certain the problem was caused by some property of the worksheet the charts where on.

I fixed it by moving them all to a new sheet and calling it a day.

Thanks for the help !